# HTML encode the output in C#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, html-encode

I need to encode all the HTML output on a site. I have a lot of different places in the code where i need to encode the output. The way that worked for me was to replace `<%=` with `<%:`and add `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode` to that string.

I.E. `<%= DisplayString %>` has been replaced with `<%: HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(DisplayString) %>`.

In this way i managed to encode this HTML output. 
My question is:  How can i replace all those `<%=` with the correct statements in the whole site?

P.S. I tried to override the Render function, but there is only HTML code and i don't have those tags there to replace.

Comment: Perhaps some regular expression to go over the whole set of files?

Comment: Isn't using `<%:` **and** `HtmlEncode` double encoding it?

Comment: @freefaller Yes it's kinda like double encoding, but the weird thing is that if I use only `<%:` or `HtmlEncode` it doesn't work

Comment: @trailmax I don't have too much experience with regular expressions. Can you please explain how can i use regular expressions in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Would it help to encode the DisplayString in Codebehind file? 
Like this:

```
     private string _displayString;
     public string DisplayString 
    {
        get { return HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(_displayString); }

    }
```

and then just load  `<%= this.DisplayString  %>`